# not quite understanding lazy-loading

Tags: jpa

I have a situation where lazy-loading is not occurring when I want it to in a one-to-many.
Obviously, I am new to this.  Why won't the SongComposers get fetched when I call s.getSongComposers()?

Here is my DAO class:

```
public class SongDAOImpl implements SongDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings(value = { "unchecked" })
    public List<Song> getAllSongsOnAlbum(int albumID) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Song s WHERE s.album.albumID  = :albumid ORDER BY s.songName");
        q.setParameter("albumid", albumID);
        List<Song> list = (List<Song>) q.getResultList();
        for (Song s: list) {
            s.getSongComposers();
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Here is my Song entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="songs")
public class Song {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="SongID")
    private int songID;

    @Column(name="SongName")
    private String songName;

    @Column(name="Length")
    private int length;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="AlbumID", referencedColumnName="AlbumID")
    private Album album;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="song")
    private List<SongComposer> songComposers;


      .... all getters/setters ......
      }
```

Here is my SongComposer entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="song_composer")
public class SongComposer {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="SongComposerID")
    private int songComposerID;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SongID", referencedColumnName="SongID")
    private Song song;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ComposerID", referencedColumnName="ComposerID")
    private Composer composer;


         ..... getters/setters .......

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it explicitly. Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Song s JOIN FETCH s.songComposers WHERE s.album.albumID  = :albumid ORDER BY s.songName"
```

Comment: Great thanks!  I had to slap a DISTINCT in there, too.  This seems to be different behavior from Hibernate, where the calling the getter will bring in the child records,automatically, I think.